# To style button with a standard SAPUI5 icon

Tags: sapui5

How to style button with a standard SAPUI5 icon?

```
    <Button
        icon="sap-icon://notes"
         text="Справки"
        press="onOpenRef"
        class=" sapThemeHighlight-asBackgroundColor "/>
```

It is necessary that the button was in the shape of a circle and green.

[image]

How can I do it (preferably standard SAPUI5 methods)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To make it green, you could use the ButtonType `Accept` although that might carry some semantic meaning.

SAPUI5 itself doesn't offer a property on the Button to make it round, so you would have to use CSS instead.
To create a Button as in your image, add the style class `roundButton` and add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```css
.roundButton .sapMBtnInner {
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}
```

Creating the Button in XML:

```xml
<Button class="roundButton" icon="sap-icon://notes" tooltip="Справки" type="Accept" />
```

and JavaScript:

```js
new sap.m.Button({
  icon: "sap-icon://notes",
  tooltip: "Справки",
  type: "Accept"
}).addStyleClass("roundButton");
```